# Make does not compile good files

Tags: c, makefile, yacc, flex-lexer

I've got a problem with a Makefile, it just compiles many time the same file.

Here are my files:

```
$ ls *
carnet.data  carnet.l  carnet.y  Makefile

struct:
carnet.c  carnet.h  ihm.c  ihm.h  struct.c  struct.h
```

Here is my Makefile:

```
CC      = gcc
LEX     = lex
YACC    = yacc
FLAGS   = -Wall -Wextra -Werror -O3 -g
ELIB    = -lfl # Flex library
TARGET  = carnet

SRC     = $(shell find struct/ -name "*.c")
OBJ     = $(SRC:.c=.o)
SRCL    = $(shell find -name "*.l")
OBJL    = lex.yy.o
SRCY    = $(shell find -name "*.y")
OBJY    = y.tab.o

all : $(TARGET)

$(TARGET) : $(OBJ) $(OBJY) $(OBJL)
    @echo "Linking"
    @echo $(SRC)
    @echo $(OBJ)
    @$(CC) $^ -o $@ $(FLAGS) $(ELIB)


$(OBJY) : $(SRCY)
    @echo $<
    @$(YACC) -d $<
    @$(CC) -c y.tab.c -o $@

$(OBJL) : $(SRCL)
    @echo $<
    @$(LEX) $<
    @$(CC) -c lex.yy.c -o $@

$(OBJ) : $(SRC)
    @echo $<
    $(CC) -c $< -o $@ $(FLAGS)

clean :
    rm y.tab.c $(OBJY) y.tab.h lex.yy.c $(OBJL)
    rm $(OBJ)

destroy :
    rm $(TARGET)

rebuilt : destroy mrpropper

mrpropper : all clean
```

And here is the output when I do a 'make':

```
struct/struct.c
gcc -c struct/struct.c -o struct/struct.o -Wall -Wextra -Werror -O3 -g
struct/struct.c
gcc -c struct/struct.c -o struct/carnet.o -Wall -Wextra -Werror -O3 -g
struct/struct.c
gcc -c struct/struct.c -o struct/ihm.o -Wall -Wextra -Werror -O3 -g
carnet.y
carnet.l
Linking
struct/struct.c struct/carnet.c struct/ihm.c
struct/struct.o struct/carnet.o struct/ihm.o
```

As we can see, when I do a 'echo $(SRC)' he finds all three files, but he only compiles the 'struct.c' file, and I don't understand why !

Thanks for your help,
Phantom

Comment: Side note not really belonging to my answer: Use `:=` instead of `=` everywhere you don't need *late expansion* to avoid confusion. With just `=`, you'll get a variable that has it's content only expanded when it is expanded itself and most of the time, this is not what you want (but sometimes it is)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SRC     = $(shell find struct/ -name "*.c")
```

You create a list here, `$(SRC)` will be `struct/struct.c struct/carnet.c struct/ihm.c`. Or any other order `find` may return, but according to your result, this seems to be the order.

```
OBJ     = $(SRC:.c=.o)
```

This creates the modified list `struct/struct.o struct/carnet.o struct/ihm.o`

```
$(OBJ) : $(SRC)
    @echo $<
    $(CC) -c $< -o $@ $(FLAGS)
```

Here we go, (partial, for clarity) expansion leads to

```
struct/struct.o struct/carnet.o struct/ihm.o : struct/struct.c struct/carnet.c struct/ihm.c
    @echo $<
    $(CC) -c $< -o $@ $(FLAGS)
```

So you have a rule applied for building 3 targets, fine. Now, `$<` expands to the **first** prerequisite, which is `struct/struct.c` here.

One possible (and common) solution if you use a `make` capable of it, e.g. *GNU make*, is to use pattern rules instead of this `find`-hack:

```
struct/%.o : struct/%.c
    @echo $<
    $(CC) -c $< -o $@ $(FLAGS)
```

Note that normally, you just maintain ONE list of the modules of your taget in your `Makefile`, usually the object files, manually, like here:

```
OBJS:= struct/struct.o struct/carnet.o struct/ihm.o
```